# How to read object after transaction Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

How to read object "data" after transaction Firestore? Why is this object created for snapshot? How to copy a snapshot directly into a document or how to read object "data"?

[image]

transaction:

```
mFirestoreRef = mFirestore.collection("item_decor").document(item_holly_id);
builder.setView(v)
    .setTitle("Добавить элемент")
    .setPositiveButton("Добавить", (dialog, which) ->
        mFirestore.runTransaction((Transaction.Function<Void>) transaction -> {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(mFirestoreRef);

            long sumUpdateData = snapshot.getLong("sum");
            int sumUpdate = (Integer) sum.getSelectedItem();

            if(sumUpdateData >= sumUpdate) {
                transaction.update(mFirestoreRef, "sum", sumUpdateData - sumUpdate);
                DocumentReference addItemRef = mFirestore.collection("list_holly")
                    .document(holly.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    .collection("item_holly").document(snapshot.getId());

                    transaction.set(addItemRef, snapshot);
                    transaction.update(addItemRef, "sum", sumUpdate);
                }
```

Read:

```
mFirestore.collection("list_holly").document(title.getTitle()).collection("item_holly")
    .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String name = document.getString("name"); // Does not work
            }
        } else {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't working because you are missing a property. To solve this, please change your get call with this:

```
mFirestore.collection("list_holly")
    .document(title.getTitle())
    .collection("item_holly")
    .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) document.get("data");
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().equals("name")) {
                    String name = entry.getValue().toString();
                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The output will be: `Decor`

The `data` property is a `Map`, so to actually get the name, you only need to iterate over that `Map`. That's it!